# Object not applicable in my scheme program

Tags: list, sorting, scheme

I'm writing a program in scheme that will allow me to manage a list of information pertaining to a student. Each element of this list is another list containing 3 items about a student: ID (string of digits), student name (string of chars), and grade (integer). I'm currently trying to write a function to sort my list of students by ID in ascending order.

My helper-function for sort-list named 'smallest' is supposed to return the smallest ID of a list passed into it. 
When I make a call to 'smallest' in my 'perform task' function under condition (= n 3) I try to print out the ID in my base case in my smallest function to see if its working, and it displays the smallest ID but then gives me an error saying ";The object #!unspecific is not applicable". I couldn't figure it out and moved on assuming that it was because I'm returning 'record' to a spot that doesn't do anything with the ID.

This logic proved to be wrong when I make a call to my 'remove' helper-function. This is supposed to remove the student element with the smallest ID. I make a test call in 'perform task' under condition (= n 2) to display the new roster that remove is supposed to return but instead I get an error saying ";The object "1" is not applicable". '1' represents the smallest ID in the list I tested it with so this leads me to believe my 'smallest' function is working but also giving me an error somewhere... If anyone can point me in the right direction to fix this problem I would greatly appreciate it!

I'm new to scheme and for this project my professor specified we are not allowed to use any set! functions, do-loops, or any built in sort functions.

```
(define smallest
  (lambda (roster record)
          (if (null? roster)
              (begin (display record) record)
              (if (> (string->number record) (string->number (car (car roster))))
                  (smallest (cdr roster) (car(car roster)))
                  (smallest (cdr roster) record)))
         ))

(define remove
  (lambda (roster record)
     (if (equal? (string->number record) (string->number (car(car roster))))   
          (cdr roster)
          (remove (list (cdr roster) (car roster)) record) 
    )))

(define performtask
  (lambda (n roster)
        (cond ((= n 0) (begin
                        (display "\n\tOption 0.")
                        (display "\nReset Roster")
                        (menu '())
                        ))
              ((= n 1) (begin
                        (display "\n\tOption 1.")
                        (display "\nLoad Roster From File")
                        (menu roster)
                        ))
              ((= n 2) (begin                                   
                        (display "\n\tOption 2.")
                        (display "\nStore Roster To File")
                        (display (list (remove roster (smallest roster (car(car roster))))))
                        (menu roster)
                        ))
              ((= n 3) (begin                                   
                        (display "\n\tOption 3.")
                        (display "\nDisplay Roster by ID")
                        (display "\nsmallest record is: ")
                        (smallest roster (car (car roster)))
                        (menu roster)
                        ))
              ((= n 4) (begin                                   
                        (display "\n\tOption 4.")
                        (display "\nDisplay Student Info")
                        (menu roster)
                        ))
              ((= n 5) (begin                                   
                        (display "\n\tOption 5.\n")
                        (display roster)
                        (newline)
                        (menu (cons (ano-read-3-items 0 '()) roster))
                        ))
              ((= n 6) (begin                                   
                        (display "\n\tOption 6.")
                        (display "\nRemove a student from Roster")
                        (menu roster)
                        ))
              ((= n 7) (begin(display "\n\tOption 7. Exit\n")
                        #t
                        ))
              (else (begin
                        (display "\n\tTask No. ")
                        (display n)
                        (display " does not exit.\n\n")
                        (menu roster)
                    )
              )
        )
  )
)

(define menu
  (lambda (roster)
        (begin
           (display "\t============================\n")
           (display "\t    MENU\n")
           (display "\t============================\n")
           (display "\t0. Reset roster\n")
           (display "\t1. Load roster from file\n")
           (display "\t2. Store roster to file\n")
           (display "\t3. Display roster sorted by ID\n")
           (display "\t4. Display student information\n")
           (display "\t5. Add a student to roster\n")
           (display "\t6. Remove a student from roster\n")
           (display "\t7. Exit\n")
           (display "\tEnter your choice: ")
           (performtask (read) roster)
        )
  )
)
```

Comment: Not the cause of this problem, but you should open a REPL and compare `(list (cdr '(1 2 3)))` to `(cdr '(1 2 3))`, and `(list '(1 2 3))` to `'(1 2 3)`.

Comment: It's the "Read-Eval-Print-Loop" — your interactive "prompt". (And no, they aren't.)

Comment: @molbdnilo oh okay I see, I used one. I think this might be the cause of the following problem. When I make a call to (display (remove roster (smallest roster (car (car roster))))), I get an error saying that ';The object ("4" "lini" "94"), passed as an argument to string->number, is not a string.' The current list when this call is made is: ((5 me 95) (4 lini 94) (3 rudy 93) (2 mark 92) (1 silas 91)). I used the string->number function for a > comparison so I assumed it would work here too, but I'm also not getting the right element of the list that I desire to even compare

Comment: @molbdnilo I think I might see my problem. When I make my recursive call to remove, I pass in (list (cdr roster) (car roster)) as the first param to remove. I think (cons (cdr roster) (car roster)) would be the appropriate call instead?

Answer (score 2):

There are wrong parentheses all over the place, and the indentation can be improved. For instance, notice the errors in this snippet of code:

```
(define smallest
  (lambda (roster record)
    ( ; this is wrong!
     (if (null? roster)
         (begin(display record) (record)) ; this is wrong, too
         (if (> (string->number record) (string->number (car (car roster))))
             (smallest (cdr roster) (let ((record (car(car roster)))) record))
             (smallest (cdr roster) record)))
     )))
```

It should be:

```
(define smallest
  (lambda (roster record)
    (if (null? roster)
         (begin
           (display record)
           record)
         (if (> (string->number record) (string->number (car (car roster))))
             (smallest (cdr roster) 
                       ; `let` is not really needed here
                       (let ((record (car (car roster))))
                         record))
             (smallest (cdr roster) record)))))
```

Notice that there must not be a pair of `()` surrounding the `if` expression, in Scheme a pair of `()` means "apply a function", they are *not* to be used as you would use a pair of `{}` in other programming languages (to define blocks of code.)

Comment: "There are wrong parentheses" At least indentation was attempted here ;p

Comment: @leppie does it look like I have removed all my wrong parentheses up top?

Comment: @SasheemSnell: not sure what you asking, but the basic rules are never end a line with an open parenthesis, and never start a line with a closing parenthesis.